# Rails Elastic Beanstalk nginx 301 redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've been able to successfully deploy and run an empty rails app using this guide: [AWS Rails Elastic Beanstalk](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Ruby_rails.html).

```
Region: us-west-2
Platform: 64bit Amazon Linux 2016.03 v2.1.0 running Ruby 2.3 (Puma)
Tier: WebServer-Standard
```

When I try to deploy and run my actual production app, the deploy is successful after adding `secret_key_base`, setting up my postgres RDS, and adding postgis to my database. But when I navigate to the url, the server hangs and the request times out. There are no application level logs being outputted and the only puma logs are the web workers booting up and ready.

I checked the nginx access logs and found that all the attempted requests had the status `301` which explains the server hanging and timing out.

```
172.31.36.144 - - [30/Apr/2016:04:54:47 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 5 "-" "-" "66.240.219.146"
172.31.36.144 - - [30/Apr/2016:04:55:02 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 5 "-" "-" "66.240.219.146"
172.31.36.144 - - [30/Apr/2016:04:55:21 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 5 "-" "-" "66.240.219.146"
```

So I think that there's an nginx configuration error that is not allowing nginx to find the correct location of my app but not sure where to look / how to correct that. Here is the only config ebextensions file I have:

```
option_settings:
  - option_name: BUNDLE_DISABLE_SHARED_GEMS
    value: "1"
  - option_name: BUNDLE_PATH
    value: "vendor/bundle"
packages:
  yum:
    git: []
```

Which is the same for the sample application I pushed as well as my production app. Very confused as to why nginx configurations would be different between the two apps but appreciate any help. Let me know if you need more logs or files.

Comment: Have you set your RDS security group to allow connection on 5432 from the security group of your EC2 instances?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Solved. The problem was that I still had the line `config.force_ssl = true` in production.rb from having ssl enabled on Heroku. I had to rebuild the environment for this change to take effect though.